# How can I diagnose Entity Framework migration errors?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, powershell

I have a project that uses Entity Framework 6.1.3 and uses the 6.9.9 MySQL connector with a MySQL 5.6.x DB. I have MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04 on a remote image and I have a matching Docker image running on my local workstation.

The Docker image works. I can use EF's Update-Database command on my Docker image. I can run my application and all the SQL things happen as they should. But nothing works on the remote. From the start, I get a timeout error when I run Update-Database from the Package Manager console in Visual Studio 2015.

I can, however, connect to the remote image with DataGrip on my workstation and perform all of the same SQL commands that are performed by Update-Database. In my mind this precludes network / firewall / configuration / permission issues. This points an accusatory finger at Visual Studio, Powershell, and Entity Framework.

How do I diagnose what is happening with the Update-Database command?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your MySQL port is 3306, when you launch docker, try publishing the port:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 my-mysql-image
```

Fire up VS after and see if that resolves your issue.